# Android FacebookSDK's AppInviteDialog.canShow() returns false

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm having problems with the AppInviteDialog provided by Facebook.

I'm using the following code snippet to show the dialog

```
if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                        .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                        .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                        .build();
                AppInviteDialog.show(activity, content);
            }
```

The problem is the sentence AppInviteDialog.canShow() is returning false.

In the Facebook Developers page, they say no login is required to invite people

> App Invites does not require Facebook Login.

But I noticed the AppInviteDialog.canShow() only returns true when I make login in my app. But if I close it an open again the dialog can not show.

Have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33419837/1054366). `canShow()` returns false typically when the content you're trying to share is not supported by the web version.