# How to handle Facebook ShareDialog.canShow() == false on Android

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook's [Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) documentation tells us to show the ShareDialog with the following code snippet:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
            .setContentDescription(
                    "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

My question is why do we need to check ShareDialog.canShow()? In what scenarios would this possibly return false and do we need to handle this scenario? The example code would just fail silently not tell the user anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I spent a lot of time yesterday trying to debug an error related to this. Facebook's docs are poor in this sense and when there is an error related to this `canShow()` method, it just fails silently, no logging at all.

So, to answer your question:

> My question is why do we need to check ShareDialog.canShow()? In what
>   scenarios would this possibly return false and do we need to handle
>   this scenario?

Based on the scenario I faced: when the user doesn't have the Facebook app installed on their device and you want to share photos (`SharePhotoContent`) or videos (`ShareVideoContent`), `canShow()` will return `false`. The reason is that Facebook SDK's WebView version doesn't support sharing this kind of content.

I found this out debugging their `FacebookActivity` class, on the `handlePassThroughError()` method. The (not logged) error message is:

*"Unable to show the provided content. This typically means that the Facebook app is not installed or up to date. If showing via the Web, this could mean that the content has properties that are not supported via this channel."*

**So, what should we do when `canShow()` returns `false`?**

It depends on your scenario. Possible solutions would be:

1. Show a dialog (or SnackBar) telling the user that they need to install the Facebook app to be able to share this kind of content;
2. Request an authentication token, log the user using the Facebook SDK, and share the content using your own dialog and calling Facebook API directly.

Possible solutions for Facebook would be include this on their documentation or log this error on LogCat.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for digging in doing the facebook's job. BTW now they do have this `ShareApi.share(linkContent, shareCallback);` in their sdk.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar you need the publish_permission to use the ShareApi.

Answer (score 0):

this answer for someone facing the same problem.

@leocadiotine was great.

From the [facebook sdk sample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/example/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java#L300), when the `ShareDialog.canShow()` return false you should use `ShareApi.share` function.

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, add:

```
<queries>
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
</queries>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// for facebook

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    // this part is optional

    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to my question. I specifically want to know why we are supposed to call ShareDialog.canShow() before showing the dialog.

Comment: ShareDialog.canShow() is checking your Facebook sdk application Id and your content type check... etc  .